# Socket.io Error on node.js app startup

Tags: node.js, sockets, express

I'm using socket.io for some internal communication in my node.js app. The code works fine on my devel machine but on main server comes out with a endless series of messages on app startup as:

```
GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=###### 404
```

Node version: 0.10.33

app.js:

```
var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3200);
...
var servio = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(servio);
var iowm = io.of('/opay');
iowm.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('done', function(data) {
    iowm.emit('op'+data.COKEY, {CPKEY: data.CPKEY});
  });
});
app.set('io', io);
servio.listen(8080);
...
app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {   // port 3200
  console.log(' listening on port '+app.get('port'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var servio = require('htpp').Server(app);
```

htpp => http ?

Comment: Fixed the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Some code was pointing to wrong socket port. Thx.